# azure pipeline multiline script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

```
steps:

- script: |
    echo "good"
    echo "nice"
```

This doesn't work. It prints 'good' successfully, but doesn't print nice and shows echo "nice" so the final output is

```
good echo 'nice'
```

I tried to remove **|** after the script: but still no luck. Any idea? I am running this on ubuntu machine.

Comment: This issue can not be reproduced. You can provide the complete YAML code see if we can help solve the issue if it is possible. Or, please try to add a Bash or Command line task and add inline script. Also, make sure the `|` is there since the script can not be recognized as two lines without it.

Comment: This problem has been resolved? since we didn't get more information. You can share the solution if it is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

I get the desired output. This is how my pipeline looks like:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: |
    echo "good"
    echo "nice"
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Answer to the question in the comments:**

This is how I pass multiple parameters to the ARM deployment task:

```
steps:
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: "MyDeployment"
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: "Resource Group"
      ConnectedServiceName: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      action: "Create Or Update Resource Group"
      resourceGroupName: "$(resourceGroupName)"
      location: "$(location)"
      templateLocation: "Linked artifact"
      csmFile: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/azuredeploy.json"
      overrideParameters: "
        -eventGridTopicName myEventGridName
        -appServicePlanName myAppServicePlan"
      deploymentMode: "Incremental"
```

Comment: How do you use mulitline when fx. providing override parameters in an ARM deployment task?

overrideParameters: >-
              '-environment_name ${{ parameters.environmentName }} -vnetAddressPrefix ${{ parameters.vnetAddressPrefix }} -subnet1Prefix ${{ parameters.subnet1Prefix }}

This doesn't seem to work I also tried with overrideParameters: |

Comment: @OliverNilsen I edited my answer and included a sample how I pass multiple parameters (not with mulitline)

Comment: I have figured it out. Posted an answer to my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228354/azure-pipelines-arm-deployment-task-yaml-multiline

Comment: @MartinBrandl It seems to me that the answer to the comment is not directly related to the original question.