# Azure pipelines ARM deployment task YAML multiline

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to use **multiline** in YAML in Azure Pipelines tasks? For instance for the ARM deployment task, there is an **overrideParameters** property. It would be nice if this could be split accross several lines instead of putting everything in one line:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
          displayName: 'ARM deploy MyFunctionAPP'
          inputs:
            deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
            azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
            subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}
            action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
            resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}
            location: 'West Europe'
            templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
            csmFile: '$(ARMtemplatesPath)\MyFunctionAPP\template.json'
            csmParametersFile: '$(ARMtemplatesPath)\MyFunctionAPP\parameters.json'
            deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
            overrideParameters: '-environment_name ${{ parameters.environmentName }} -vnetAddressPrefix ${{ parameters.vnetAddressPrefix }} -subnet1Prefix ${{ parameters.subnet1Prefix }} -APIkey ${{ parameters.APIkey }} -queueName ${{ parameters.queueNameMyQueue }} -SendGridAPIkey ${{ parameters.SendGridAPIkey }} -StorageConnectionAppSetting ${{ parameters.StorageConnectionAppSetting }}'
```

Is it somehow possible to split the overrideParameters values on multiple lines?

Comment: Actually I saw that post before answering this one and I have tried it and got errors on not being properly formatted.

Comment: Please update what you tried and which errors you got

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
overrideParameters: >-
  -environment_name "${{ parameters.environmentName }}" 
  -vnetAddressPrefix "${{ parameters.vnetAddressPrefix }}" 
  -subnet1Prefix "${{ parameters.subnet1Prefix }}"
  -APIkey "${{ parameters.APIkey }}"
  -queueName "${{ parameters.queueNameMyQueue }}" 
  -SendGridAPIkey "${{ parameters.SendGridAPIkey }}"
  -StorageConnectionAppSetting "${{ parameters.StorageConnectionAppSetting }}"
```

So using `>-` on a single line and then using double-quotes to surround settings values works.

Comment: More inconsistent cryptic undocumented YAML. Oh well, it works. Where did you find this?

Comment: I cannot remember to be honest. It was some time ago. But I remember that it was a lot of trial and error before I made it work.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it somehow possible to split the overrideParameters values on
> multiple lines?

According to the document [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#string), we could use a pipe character (`|`) for multiline strings:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
          displayName: 'ARM deploy MyFunctionAPP'
          inputs:
            deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
            azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
            subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}
            action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
            resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}
            location: 'West Europe'
            templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
            csmFile: '$(ARMtemplatesPath)\MyFunctionAPP\template.json'
            csmParametersFile: '$(ARMtemplatesPath)\MyFunctionAPP\parameters.json'
            deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
            overrideParameters: |
             -environment_name ${{ parameters.environmentName }}
             -vnetAddressPrefix ${{ parameters.vnetAddressPrefix }}
             -subnet1Prefix ${{ parameters.subnet1Prefix }}
             -APIkey ${{ parameters.APIkey }}
             -queueName ${{ parameters.queueNameMyQueue }}
             -SendGridAPIkey ${{ parameters.SendGridAPIkey }}
             -StorageConnectionAppSetting ${{ parameters.StorageConnectionAppSetting }}
```

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210#21699210) for some more details.